# "Desktop" directory not appearing in user's Finder, but otherwise there

Tags: icloud, finder, big-sur, folders

I can view the *Desktop* directory (and all its contents) by:

1. Zsh: `ls /Users/MyName` gives a list of directories, including *Desktop*
2. Minimising all apps.
3. An *iCloud* shortcut to the left within *Finder*. This is weird because I'm not connected to *iCloud*, and because finding the file path of an item in the *Desktop* (using this shortcut) gives */Users/MyName/Desktop*, which makes no sense to me if it's supposed to be on *iCloud*. [FYI, to find the file path I drag-and-drop an item into the terminal screen.]

To check that I'm in the right directory when the *Desktop* folder is missing (in Finder GUI), I dragged the Music folder into the terminal and got: */Users/MyName/Music*

It's a brand new M1 Macbook.

I've tried:

- Restarting (no change)
- Creating a new folder called "Desktop" using the GUI, which prompts '*The name "Desktop" is already taken*.'

I'd like to know why *Finder* appears to be out-of-sync?

Something that may be a cause for this issue is that I changed the home folder name, and followed [Apple's advice on to how to](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201548) do it. Note that using all the above methods the file path consistently lists the new name (the old name was *given name* + *surname*, now it's just *given name*, so it's a fairly obvious difference).

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that if you (for example) opened a Finder window, hit `command`+`shift`+`g`, and entered `~` into the dialogue box then pressed `enter`, there is no folder named Desktop in the contents of the Finder window? Could you add a screenshot to this question of the Finder window after following the above process?

Comment: @Scottmeup, Yep. I had just been using the shortcut to access the home directory, but doing it your way leads to the exact same situation: All contents are there except `Desktop`. I don't see a need for a screenshot, and this isn't actually my laptop (I'm setting it up for a friend) so that'd be a privacy issue.

Comment: If you did this because you set up an account then did a migration, it's probably easier to start over & migrate at the correct time, than try to re-patch all the perms after an account change. [Been there, done that, got the t-shirt]

Comment: @Tetsujin, You're right. I'm not stressed about this at all, but I'd like to know how this is even possible.

Comment: Account perms are complex:\ I've fought my way throught this before, making a new admin account then migrating - to realise you end up with 2 accounts to patch together. Not a mistake I'll ever make again. Quicker to start over.

Comment: It works well if you don't try to out-think it. You can't treat it like nix with a posh GUI. It definitely isn't, perms are much more aggressive & the protected system is … intransigent ;)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You write you are not connected to iCloud, but I have to ask: could it be that you've added your Desktop and Documents files to iCloud Drive? See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206985 for details.

Comment: @jaume, it seems that MacOS added `Desktop` and `Documents` to iCloud drive automatically. I moved them back and turned off iCloud, and this solved the problem. I didn't post this as an answer, as it didn't explain why the directory path in shell was inconsistent with Finder.

Comment: @Elliott I'm glad you solved the issue. I'd still post your comment as an answer since the (seeming) inconsistency in the directory path may be a implementation detail, similar to how the contents of the Applications folder differ when displayed in Finder or in Terminal.